# Core Data One to Many Relationship with NULL

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a one-to-many relationship in my core data model which looks like:

```
- data1
- data2
- RELATIONSHIP: dataSet2
```

My problem is that sometimes the dataSet2 method must be null (When there is no datSet2). How would I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to set it like this in Interface Builder:

[image: Core Data relationship settings]

Make sure the "Minimum" checkbox is unchecked.